servicenow gliderecord query behavior
Pretty new to snow and javascript, trying to get the list of group a user belong to.
The relation  is done by the table sys_user_grmember but when i try to filter the table via a addquery, it return the whole table without any constraint.
Here is a small test (fix script server side) I do in a PDI that fail (debugger show no filter content in the grGroupMembers gliderecord.
I try adding a '=' and 'is' as second argument (avoiding the 'CONTAINS' that is logically not correct and fail also).
var grGM = new GlideRecord( 'sys_user_grmember');
grGM.query();
// take second for test purpose (in PDI second in the table have another user than first)
grGM.next();
grGM.next();
DestUserID = grGM.user;


// failing part below

var grGroupMembers = new GlideRecord( 'sys_user_grmember');

    // load user group existing
    grGroupMembers.addquery( 'user', DestUserID );
    grGroupMembers.query();
    while( grGroupMembers.next()){
        GroupsExisting.push( grGroupMembers.group );
    }

Debugger show a DestUserID and grGroupMember have another one:
- on first record it's different and should not be in the scope
- on second it's the same ID that is normal for this code
All sample of gliderecord in snow doc and several code on the web about group copying show the same code (except variable names).

damned, dummy error.
"addQuery" and not "addquery".
Both syntax checker and debugger don't block on it. Works as it should
